# How to check if thre is a line of mirror symmetry in a polygon?

Tags: math, geometry, polygon

Is there an algorithm for detecting if a polygon has a line of mirror symmetry, for example, for a polygon on the image below:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Calculate [image moments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_moment#Examples_2) for vertex set of polygon.

For example - sum all `x[i]` and `y[i]` for vertices and divide by number of vertices to get centroid coordinates (`cx=m10/m00 and cy=m01/m00`).

Do similar for central moments. For example:

```
mu11 = sum((x[i]-cx)*(y[i]-cy))
```

Build line with angle `Theta` (in example section) through centroid.

If polygon has mirror symmetry, every vertex will have another vertex as mirrored image - it is enough to find any pair, then check another pairs in order)

For reference - [how to get mirror point against line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65252818/quickly-compute-reflection-of-point-about-line-described-by-two-points/65255637#65255637)

```
L = A + AB * ScalarProduct(AB, AP) / ScalarProduct(AB, AB)
Mirror point
P' = P + 2*(L-P) = 2*L-P
```

Comment: The link is a boilerplate with a lot of complex formulas for image processing, I don't see how this can be applied to a polygon.

Comment: I added example